# support a "Most Popular" query in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

If I wanted to do a "most liked" article query in neo 4j, where "liked" is a relationship between user and article, would the best way be to:

1. Keep a totalLikes count property in the article itself and do a sort on that property in a cypher query?  That property would be updated everytime somone liked an article.

Or

1. Keep an index with totalLikes for each article.  I would have to delete and re-add the index entry every time the article was liked.

I think I read in the documentation that queries cannot be sorted on total relationships count .

Answer (score 1):

So, you can do:

```
start user=node(*)
match user-[rel:liked]->article
return count(rel) as likeCount, article
order by likeCount desc;
```

http://console.neo4j.org/r/5do0qr

Comment: how is the peroformance on this query.  Is this recommneded over using an index?  We would be querying across all articles...

Comment: node(*) is usually not recommended for big datasets... if you have an index for users you could use that as a start point.

Comment: so I take it I should create a numeric lucene index for each post, updating/incrementing it on each like?  Does the REST API support this on Heroku?